# Supplementing with ethanol? Is that a thing

Tags: original-gravity

I'm transferring my first white IPA to secondary tomorrow. It smells great, but there is one problem.  A really low OG. I can only assume my protein rest wasn't sufficient to break down the proteins in the unmalted grain. A friend of mine joked about adding everclear to it. I laughed but thought about it and roughly 30 oz of ethanol would put me in the range of a typical white ipa. It's kinda cheating but I worked really hard on this recipe and I want to salvage something.  Is that something brewers can do in a pinch?

Comment: I'd taste it and if you like the taste, don't worry about the alcohol content.

Comment: You are probably right. After all session IPAs are getting popular these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a  protein rest is based on the type of malt you use and how it was malted.  It is almost never necessary for any type of malt or beer.  It certainly isn't necessary for the type of malt you use for an IPA.  So, whatever your issue is, it isn't related to a protein rest.  Unless you have really undermodified malt (which is almost impossible to find), protein breakdown will be accomplished at "normal" mash temps.

You can certainly add ethanol of you want to...it's your beer!  But you might find it adds a harsh alcoholic heat.  You might be best off to do it by the glass to taste.

Comment: White IPAs do not use typical pale malts. Typically 50% of the grain is unmalted and requires a protein rest.  Unmalted grain is not modified at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that.  But just because it uses unmalted wheat does not mean it needs a protein rest.  And it's just as common for a White IPA to use malted wheat as unmalted.